# How to compare the limitation of $\frac{\log_2(x)}{ x^{(1/5)}}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, logarithms

I want to compare the time complexity of $\log_2(x)$ and $x^{(1/5)}$ but find hard to simplify them, I used Demos (a website) to draw the lines of them and find $log_2(x)$ is always higher than $x^{(1/5)}$, however, I do not know how to prove it.

Here is my work (not sure if it is correct)

I use $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\log_2(x)}{x^{(1/5)}}$, if the result is close to infinity so that the $log_2(x)$ is growing faster than $x^{(1/5)}$.

here to tell it, so I find derivatives of them: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{(\log_2(x))'}{(x^{(\frac{1}{5})})'}$ = $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{x \cdot \ln 2}}{\frac{1}{5}\cdot x^{(-\frac{4}{5})}}$

then I stuck here, how should I continue the provement?

Comment: How about simplifying? $\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{x^{-4/5}}=\frac{1}{x^{1/5}}$. The rest are constant

Comment: @Taladris, so the constant is nothing, and $x^{1/5}$ will close to the infinity when x become infinitely high, the $\frac{1}{x^{1/5}}$ will infinitely close to 0, does that mean the $log_{2}(n)$'s complexity is actually smaller than $x^{1/5}$, $log_{2}(n)$=O($x^{1/5}$)?

Comment: Indeed, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^{1/5}}=0$ since $\frac{1}{5}>0$. Multiplying the function by a constant will not change this (the limit will be $\frac{1}{5\ln(2)}\times 0=0$ by Limit Laws). Yes, $x^{1/5}$ is growing faster that $\log_2(x)$. More generally, $x^\alpha$ is growing faster that $\log_a(x)$ for every $\alpha>0$ and $a>1$ (The proof is similar, using L'Hospital's Rule).

Comment: @Taladris, thank you so much, now I understand that, and simply using a function drawing website to paint the two functions and compare them is a bad idea.

Comment: Not necessarily. But remember that when considering limits at infinity, we are looking for **large** values of $x$. So $x^{1/5}$ will be larger than $\log_2(x)$ for $x$ large: there exists some value $a$ such that $x^{1/5}>\log_2(x)$ for every $x>a$. But for $x$ not so large, it is possible that $\log_2(x)>x^{1/5}$ Using a computer, it seems that $a\simeq 5.7\times 10^6$, which is quite large.

Comment: @Taladris, this variable a is very large, I only looked at it about 50000, I thought this is large enough, never thought it can be this large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$L=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\frac{1}{x \cdot \ln 2}}{\frac{1}{5}\cdot x^{(-\frac{4}{5})}}$$

From this step, you can simplify it first,

$$L=\frac{5}{\ln2}\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{x\cdot x^{(-\frac{4}{5})}}=\frac{5}{\ln2}\cdot \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{5}}}=0$$

This means actually $x^{1/5}$ is much larger than $\log_2 x$, as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

After your comments, instead of applying the L'Hôpital's rule, you can go faster .

Substituting $\thinspace x\mapsto 2^{5t}$, then you get,

$$
\begin{align}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log_2(x)}{x^{\frac 15}}&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {5t}{2^t}\\
&=5\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t}{2^t}\\
&=0\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

Because, the polynomial $t$ grows asymptotically slower than $2^t$ as $t\to \infty\thinspace. $ Therefore ,

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac {t}{2^t}=0$$

---

In general, let $P_n(x)$ be a polynomial with degree $n$ and $a>1$ . Then :

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {P_n(x)}{a^x}=0\thinspace .$$